# BeanCreationException : Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'

Tags: java, xml

Please help me on this issue I'm stuck on this from last two days. I'm working with spring MVC + spring security + hibernate , when I try to use UserAuthenticationProvider in Authentication-Manager I get this issue and I don't know what's wrong in my code. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1049)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:28)
    at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:20)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 73 more

```
Web.xml

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
    <servlet-   class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
              org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/sdnext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
            </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.box.practice.common.web.AuthFilter</filter-class> 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>host</param-name>
        <param-value>http://172.17.4.15:8089/Spr_SperSec_DB</param-value>
       <!--    <param-value>http://localhost:38080/HRAlign_V3Talent</param-  value> -->
    </init-param>
</filter> 
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

sdnext-servlet.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<annotation-driven></annotation-driven>

<context:property-placeholder   location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.box.practice"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

<beans:bean id="jspViewResolver"   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass"   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
             <beans:value>com.box.practice.security.login.model.Users</beans:value>
             <beans:value>com.box.practice.personalDetails.personalInfo.model.Concept_Underst anding_CURD</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}  </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}  </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop   key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</beans:prop>               
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean> 

</beans:beans>

sdnext-security.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


<security:http auto-config="true" >  
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"  /> 
      <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/security/login/index.html"  
       authentication-failure-url="/security/login/fail2login" />  
      <security:logout logout-success-url="/security/login/logout" />  
 </security:http>



  <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"  class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder"/>
 <beans:bean class="com.box.practice.common.web.UserAuthenticationProvider" 
    id="userAuthenticationProvider" autowire-candidate="true">
</beans:bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="userAuthenticationProvider"/>
     <security:authentication-provider>
      <security:user-service>
        <security:user name="abc" password="xyz" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
      </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider> 
</security:authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>

UserAuthenticationProvider.class

public class UserAuthenticationProvider implements Authentication{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired HttpSession session;
@Autowired PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired UserCredentialsService userCredentialsService;

public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws  AuthenticationException{
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token =  (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
    String userName = token.getName();String key="";

    String jCryption=(String)token.getCredentials();
    key = (String) session.getAttribute("jCryptionKey");
    if(key==null || key.equals(""))
    {
        throw new PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException("");
    }
    String passwordStr = AesCtr.decrypt(jCryption, key, 256); // added jar  javacryption-1.0.jar
    String password = passwordEncoder.encode(passwordStr);

    User user=null;
    user = userCredentialsService.authenticateUser(userName, password);

    if(user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username/password");
    }else{
        if(!passwordEncoder.matches(passwordStr, user.getPassword())){
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username/password");
        }
    }
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,password);  
}
```

Comment: can you please check comments you have your in your `web.xml` file. I dont see whether it is ending

Comment: all comments in web.xml file is ending properly.

Comment: Can any one help me on this.....!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!